# Placeholder Code still visible when "view source code", even though placeholder visible property set to false from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-placeholder

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="pnlThanks" runat="server" Visible="false">
          <p><asp:Literal  ID="lblReceipt" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
</asp:PlaceHolder>   
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="pnlForm" runat="server" Visible="true">
         <form id="form1" runat="server" class="busgroup-form">
          //// All form controls
          </form>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code Behind file:

```
  Protected Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmdsubmit.Click
      form1.Controls.Clear()
      pnlForm.Visible = False
      pnlThanks.Visible = True
  End Sub
```

So, after submitting form when "pnlThanks" placeholder is visible, I can see proper contents displayed on page. But when I do "view source" on the browser, I see the source code for form and not the content inside "pnlThanks" placeholder.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all of your controls within the `<form>` tag, because ASP.NET depends upon the `form` to do postbacks, etc.

You can only have one `<form>` tag in your page.

Change your code to this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="busgroup-form">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pnlThanks" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <p><asp:Literal  ID="lblReceipt" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="pnlForm" runat="server" Visible="true">
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</form>
```

Comment: Currently there is only one form with runat=server tag

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected when I tested it. My guess is there is another `pnlForm.Visible = True` in your code elsewhere that is executed on your postback.

Comment: Checked thoroughly. Couldn't find any :(

Answer (score 0):

pnlThanks isn't rendered if visible=false, therefore it won't show in the source. You can use CSS (display=none) to hide it on start and change when needed.

Comment: On submit, it is set to visible = true from code behind. See above code.